# Link formed using printing scriptlet and sent to email are executed automatically

Tags: google-apps-script

Background: I have created a sidebar for a Google Sheet, using GAS (Apps Script). The sheet contains database of people, and record of POs. The app can send the PO to a particular via Gmail, with ACCEPT and REJECT links in it.

```
<span id="acceptLink">
      <a href="<?= url ?>?poyear=<?= poyear ?>&state=Accept&name=<?= name ?>&did=<?= draftid ?>" aria-invalid="true">
        <span class="accept"><?= stringAccept ?></span>
      </a>     
    </span>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span id="rejectLink">
      <a href="<?= url ?>?poyear=<?= poyear ?>&state=Reject&name=<?= name ?>&did=<?= draftid ?>" aria-invalid="true">
        <span class="reject"><?= stringReject ?></span>
      </a>
    </span>
```

This scriptlets are edited and inserted according to the user selected for the respective PO. A copy of the same email, without the ACCEPT and REJECT buttons are saved when someone is asked for availability. If they click ACCEPT, this draft is sent to them.

Now the issue:
I have around 70 people in my DB. But if a few of them are sent this "availability check," there is immediate "REJECT" response from this ( the people doesn't know they sent Rejection ). While almost 99% people are not facing this issue, this happens to only a few!

Now I need help to fix this. I don't understand why it is happening.
Also how do I see if I get the REJECT from them in on my hosted page (do get) of the same app. Putting some code here just in case.

```
function doGet(e){
  if(gIfSim)
  {
    //Debug code.
    //e={parameter:{state:"Accept", name:"Preet Mehta", did:"r-8262072107973556655"}};
  }

  //***THESE ARE THE VARS PASSED BACK USING THE SCRIPTLET***
  var passedInIPState = e.parameter.state;
  var draftID = e.parameter.did;
  var poYear = e.parameter.poyear;

  //poYear will be like "2223"
  var sheetName = "PO " + poYear;

  var wsPO = getSheet(sheetName);
  var colAlPO = getColAlpha("PO");
  
  var messageFromDraft;
  try
  {
    //CORRESPONDING DRAFT IS AVAILABLE IN THE GMAIL - CHECKED
    messageFromDraft = GmailApp.getDraft(draftID);
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('rejectResponse').evaluate();    
  }

  //IF THE FLOW REACHES HERE THEN THE VALID ACCEPT/REJECT RESPONSE
  var getMessagePlain = messageFromDraft.getMessage().getPlainBody();
  Logger.log(getMessagePlain);

  var j = JSON.parse(getMessagePlain);
  Logger.log(j);

  var rowIndex = j.rIndex;

  var airedCount = wsPO.getRange(colAlPO.airedcounter + rowIndex).getValue();
  airedCount = airedCount - 1;
  wsPO.getRange(colAlPO.airedcounter + rowIndex).setValue(airedCount);

  var valueOfstatusINPO = wsPO.getRange(colAlPO.status + rowIndex).getValue();
  
  if( passedInIPState == "Accept" && valueOfstatusINPO == "WAITING FOR RESPONSE")
  {
    //BUSINESS LOGIC FOR ACCEPT RESPONSE AND THE PAGE IS SERVED
    
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('acceptResponse').evaluate();
  }
  else if( passedInIPState == "Accept" && valueOfstatusINPO != "WAITING FOR RESPONSE")
  {    
    //BUSINESS LOGIC FOR ACCEPT RESPONSE STATE 2 AND THE PAGE IS SERVED

    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('rejectResponse').evaluate();
  }
  else if(passedInIPState == "Reject")
  {
    //BUSINESS LOGIC FOR REJECT RESPONSE AND THE PAGE IS SERVED
    //THIS CODE CHANGES THE PO SHEET ROW TO REJECT WHICH ALSO REFLECTS THAT BEHAVIOR

    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('firstReject').evaluate();
  }
}
```

Comment: So you mean that you receive a REJECT from people who never clicked on any link? Or from people who did click, but on the on the accept and not reject link?

Comment: I receive REJECT from some particular email IDs and they haven't clicked any link. 99% of my database has not shown this behavior. But few particulars are weird!

Comment: You might receive REJECT when the condition `else if( passedInIPState == "Accept" && valueOfstatusINPO != "WAITING FOR RESPONSE")` is fullfilled, but I don't see how you can get a REJECT if no one clicked on any link and did not run the WebApp in any other way . Maybe you can inporporate more logs into your `doGet` function - e.g. log the user email and `passedInIPState` and see if somehow your `doGet` is triggered for the users with the weird behaviour when you are actually not expecting it.

Comment: If `doGet` is never triggered for those users than the REJECT must somehow get into your database in a different way.

Comment: doGet is triggered. But how that's the question. The users are not clicking it. And this behavior is to particular emails only. The main question is, no one is clicking the link which in the email that has been sent from a sidebar custom menu!